# how is the "best" split at node determined in matlab RF package?

Tags: random-forest, matlab

Does someone know how the "best" split at a node is determined in the [MATLAB RF package](https://code.google.com/p/randomforest-matlab/)?

I have more than two classes, and just wondered how it is working. Is the package using the Gini impurity? (Well I would not know exactly how that works, but at least I would know then what to google for.)

Comment: I don't know about that package, but if you use the TreeBagger class in Matlab (in the stats toolbox) then it uses the ClassRegTree class to build the trees which has options about what function it bases the split on but the Gini Index is the default option.

Comment: If they had someone competent and did their job well (and Mathworks tends to do pretty well at that) then it will be consistent with the published papers of Breiman and the implementations in R for randomforest.  (http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_papers.htm)